# soql query in salesforce

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResultCall = [ SELECT Account_vod__c, count(Id) 
                                        FROM Call2_vod__c 
                                        WHERE Call_Date_vod__c >= :QuarterStartDate
                                          AND Call_Date_vod__c <= :QuarterEndDate 
                                          AND Account_Type__c =: accStaticRec.Account_Type__c 
                                          AND Territory_vod__c =: accStaticRec.Territory__c 
                                          AND Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod' 
                                          AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
                                            OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
                                            OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
                                          AND Account_vod__c IN :accIdSet                                                           
                                          AND Activity_Type__c <> 'Staff'
                                        GROUP BY Account_vod__c ];

 AggregateResult[] groupedResultCall = [SELECT Account_vod__c, count(Id) 
                                        FROM Call2_vod__c 
                                        WHERE Call_Date_vod__c >= :QuarterStartDate 
                                          AND Call_Date_vod__c <= :QuarterEndDate 
                                          AND Account_Type__c =:accStaticRec.Account_Type__c 
                                          AND Territory_vod__c = :accStaticRec.Territory__c 
                                          AND Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod' 
                                          AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
                                            AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
                                            AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
                                          AND Account_vod__c IN :accIdSet  
                                          AND Activity_Type__c <> 'Staff'
                                        GROUP BY Account_vod__c ];
```

which query is correct. Please correct me

Answer (score 1):

2nd one is correct.

```
AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
```

I think you want to retrieve those rows for which 'Call_Type_vod__c' value is other than these values ('Call Only', 'Event Only', 'Event Detail') .
So 2nd will work.

1st query will return all the rows

```
AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only one difference between queries is on nested AND condition

```
AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
  OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
  OR Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
```

VS

```
AND (Call_Type_vod__c != 'Call Only' 
  AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Only' 
  AND Call_Type_vod__c != 'Event Detail')
```

and it fully depends on your data model and your expectation regarding the result of this query.